# Static file with query parameter

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I have an nginx web-server and CodeIgniter as the framework.

Static files are properly server (.js, .css and others), but having query parameters makes nginx pass the request to CodeIgniter.

So `www.example.com/js/file.js` is served, but `www.example.com/js/file.js?key=value` goes to CodeIgniter and returns 404.

How can I set nginx to server static files, even though query parameters are passed ?

Comment: I do not see `.js` in latter url.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited.

Comment: Well, show your nginx config

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you maping the querystrings somewhere? Can you share your nginx server blocks to see where it may go wrong?